# After navigating between pages on Windows Phone: "Argument Exception:Value does not fall in the expected range"

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have a little project for Windows Phone 8.1
Now there are two pages: RecordPage and SavePage. I have to transfer object of my VideoRecorder class between them.

In RecordPage:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        SavePage savePage = e.Content as SavePage;
        if (savePage != null)
        {
            savePage.videoRecorder = videoRecorder;
        }
    }
```

In SavePage:

```
async private void SaveVideo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressRing.IsActive = true;
        await videoRecorder.SaveRecordAsync(textBox_VideoName.Text);
        progressRing.IsActive = false;
    }
```

In VideoRecorder:

```
........
private StorageFile tempFile;
........
async public Task<bool> SaveRecordAsync(string videoName)
{
    GC.Collect();            
    MediaClip clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(tempFile);
    int fullDuration = ........
```

Application crashes on `CreateFromFileAsync(tempFile)` with `"Argument Exception:Value does not fall in the expected range"`.

When I tried to run `VideoRecorder.SaveRecordAsync` with random name at record page - it works fine. But when I transfer `RecordPage.videoRecorder` to `SavePage.videoRecord` and run `SaveRecordAsync` - it crashes.

I running application on device (Lumia 635)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing videoName to SaveRecordAsync function but you are trying to run CreateFromFileAsync with some "tempFile" that you don't included anywhere.

Comment: Excuse me please. I forgot to explain that tempFile is a VideoRecorder's property.

//post edited

Comment: Ok, so maybe when you are trying to save it from another page, you are in wrong thread. 
Try this one `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => await videoRecorder.SaveRecordAsync(textBox_VideoName.Text));`